# How to safely remove fields from create content - project

Tags: entities

I am customizing the Project Management (pm) module. When I create a new Project content type I do not need some of the fields such as price and currency for my particular application. I am concerned that if I use the Fields UI to delete them that when a new version of pm is release that I'll have problems installing it. I also worry that I might mess up the database.

I have made these fields hidden, but they still appear on the create new Project content page.

Are my worries baseless?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest just hiding the unwanted field via a hook_form_alter, either by setting `$form['unwanted_field']['#access'] = FALSE`, or by using the hide() on that element. If the field is a required field, you'll want to alter that property as well, or set a value before hiding it or setting '#access' to false.

if you want to actually delete the field, you can use drush to run field_delete_field(). For example, `drush eval 'field_delete_field("unwanted_field")'` should work (untested).

Comment: Is there a way I can safely use the Fields UI instead of getting into drush & api?

Comment: I don't think you can if they are being rendered by the module code. You will have to either use the approaches I have mentioned or possibly the theming layer, which is still coding.

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe I could create a new content type using just the fields that are needed. Would that work?

Comment: That would work, but since you're using the PM project it may not use your content in any of it's views automatically. There may be another solution. You can implement the field permissions module (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), which allows you to control which fields can be seen, and I'm pretty sure it's all via an interface instead of having to write code. I'm not sure if the settings you save will be lost when you update the PM module, but it's worth a shot. There's a video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmqlBBSoRWU

Answer (score 0):

The Field Permissions module works, but I decided that my situation was so simple that I created a new content type for tasks and another for projects using the model of the pm modules. It works well.